# AWS Chime - meeting has created - how to join to that meeting

Tags: reactjs, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I've created meeting using Amazon chime SDK in React js. Through this I can able to start a meeting. How some one can join to that meeting or add attendees to that meeting.

Comment: Hello Rawi! To help the community answer the question, please include some context and describe what you're expecting to have. I tried to answer as broad as I could to cover more cases, but would be better if you change the question to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to create a meeting hosted on AWS Chime programmatically, the SDK isn't what you're looking for:

> Amazon Chime SDK works independently of any Amazon Chime administrator accounts, and it does not affect meetings hosted on Amazon Chime. Instead, the Amazon Chime SDK provides builder tools for developers to use to build their own meeting applications. ([the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/meetings-sdk.html))

Otherwise, to build your own app, first, you need a back-end to:

- Create a meeting
- Get an attendee for everyone who is allowed to join the conference

Then create a client app:

- receive meeting and attendee details in your client app and initialize a meeting session with these parameters
- connect audio and video devices
- add observer, event and output handlers, etc

[Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/dg/chime-components.html) a good place to start and [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-js/tree/master/demos) you can find various demos. The most common answers can be found in the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/chime/chime-sdk/faq/).